# How to support placeholder attribute in IE8 and IE9 without jQuery dependency in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, placeholder

Is there any drop in directive in angular js to support placeholder in IE 8 and IE 9. There are a bunch of libs that I found but all of them had jQuery dependency. Need to achieve it **without jQuery dependency**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create a [custom placeholder directive](https://github.com/vikasgulati/angularjs-placeholder) to handle it without any jQuery dependency.

Comment: Depending on use case, you might need to wrap each input in its own `display: inline-block;` container.

Comment: Also, I'm using it with bootstrap and had to add `z-index: 3;`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to implement placeholder attributes for older browsers in an application my company was developing using our own custom placeholder directive without **Jquery** such as yours.

It was giving us some trouble because everytime it would just suddenly stop from working and the placeholder was taking too long to appear when using IE8/ IE9.

Then I found this guy and it works beautifully:

https://github.com/cvn/angular-shims-placeholder

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use http://modernizr.com/ to check for placeholder suppport.

```
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) { ... }
```

Comment: I do not want to just check for placeholder support but also provide a  placeholder pollyfill/directive for them.